# Cannot resolve symbol USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE

Tags: android, android-vibration

I am able to make my android device vibrate using
`v.vibrate(pattern, -1);`
However, the android [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) describes another link to insert an AudioAttribute. 
However, the following line gives me an error.

```
    cannot resolve symbol USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE: 
    v.vibrate(pattern, -1, USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Vibrator androidVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
long[] pattern = { 0, 1000, 2000 };
androidVibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constant `USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE` is a property of `AudioAttribute` which means you have to reference it properly:

```
v.vibrate(pattern, -1, new AudioAttributes.Builder()
         .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE).build());
```

and don't forget to include `android.media.AudioAttributes`.

Comment: v.vibrate(pattern, -1, AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE);
The error says that it expects an integer argument.

Comment: I updated my answer. Also keep in mind, that this is only available in Android 5.0 and newer.

Comment: Thanks. My code builds without error. however, I cannot yet understand the difference in the meaning of these two lines of code:

a) v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
b) v.vibrate(pattern, -1, new AudioAttributes.Builder()      .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE).build());

Comment: With the `AudioAttributes` you can specify some sort of 'context'. If you don't need that I suggest to use `v.vibrate(pattern, -1);`.